# Listar array em table na horizontal e vertical

Tags: php, html, for, foreach

Estou tentando listar o nome da empresa na horizontal, as quantidades dos produtos logo abaixo de cada nome de empresa, e o nome do produto na primeira coluna na vertical.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código é esse, mas não esta listando como eu preciso.

```
<br>
<table border="1" width="100%" >   
  <tr>
    <th>Nomes das Empresas  &#9658;<br>Nomes dos produtos &#9660;</th>

    <?php
    require 'config.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM empresas inner join produtos group by nomeEmpresa ";
    $dados = $pdo->query($sql);

    if ($dados->rowCount() > 0) {
      foreach ($dados->fetchAll() as $om) {
        $idEmpresa = $om['idEmpresa'];
        $nomeEmpresa = $om['nomeEmpresa'];
        $nomeProduto = $om['nomeProduto'];

        echo "<th>";echo $om['nomeEmpresa']; echo "</th>";// Lista o  nome das empresas na horizonttal

      }

      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<th>";echo $om['nomeProduto']; echo "</th>"; // Lista o  nome de um dos produtos na vertical

      $sql = "SELECT count(idEmpresa) as soma FROM empresas  ";
      $sql = $pdo->query($sql);
      $contar = $sql->fetch();
      $quantidadeEmpresas =$contar['soma'];

      for ($x=1; $x <=$quantidadeEmpresas ; $x++) { 


        $sql = "SELECT quantidade_produto   FROM rel_empresa_produtos WHERE idEmpresa = '$x'   ";
        $dados = $pdo->query($sql);
        if ($dados->rowCount() > 0) {
          foreach ($dados->fetchAll() as $om) {

            $quantidade_produto = $om['quantidade_produto'];

            echo "<th>";echo $om['quantidade_produto']; echo "</th>";

          } 

        }
      }

}
echo "</table>";
```

---

Tabelas do banco de dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque na pergunta os esquemas das tabelas `empresas` e `produtos`

Comment: Bom dia amigo, coloquei os print do DB, se poder me ajudar agradeço muito.Obrigado.

Comment: Dá uma analisada na edição que fiz e veja se está do seu agrado. Se não tiver eu reverto.

Comment: Você editou apenas a apresentação digamos assim, o código continua o mesmo certo?   Pode me ajudar a deixar da maneira que eu preciso?

Answer (score -1):

Tenta "encapsular" todos os th dos nomes das empresas num único tr também.

Algo assim:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th>Empresa 1</th>
     <th>Empresa 2</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: O nome das empresas ja está na horizontal, agora preciso deixar o nome do produto na primeira coluna da direita e as quantidade lado a lado e abaixo do nome de cada empresa, isso é que não estou acertando.

Comment: Então, não ficou muito claro, seria melhor mostrar um print de como você quer. Você quer uma tabela simples com o header, e a listagem seria: NOME_PRODUTO, QTD_EMP1, QTD_EMP2, QTD_EMP3 ?
Se for isso, é só setar a primeira coluna como <td>$nomeProduto</td> e as demais você usa o <td>$om['quantidade_produto']</td>, tudo isso numa <tr> só.

To me baseando por alto, não sei o que a query retorna.

Comment: Coloquei  a imagem, preciso que fique dessa forma ai.